# What is the Smartsheet Date format?

Tags: c#, date, smartsheet-api

Smartsheet.Api.InvalidRequestException: 'The value for cell in column 324579127256964, 19/04/2018, did not conform to the strict requirements for type DATE.'

I'm receiving the above error trying to insert 19/04/2018 into a column programmatically using C#.

As the error states it's not conforming to the the strict requirements. What are the requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to follow the requirements refer to the api docs (http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#cell-reference)

The cell value representation of a date is according to the ISO 8601 format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):
[image: DATE cell value format]
For example, 2018-04-19 instead of 19/04/2018 should work

If you want to disable the strict requirement checking for a cell include **"strict": false** in the Cell object in your request body.